# catch a break in trio async generator

Tags: python, asynchronous, break, python-trio

I have a strange error with an asynchronous **trio** loop. When I interrupt the loop with **break** during iteration, I expected the print statement `"exit 2"` to be printed before the statement `"--- Hello ---"`. But when I run this example, the code after the iteration is executed before the code in the GeneratorExit exception.

```py
import trio

class Bar:
    async def __aiter__(self):
        for x in range(10):
            try:
                yield x
            except Exception as e:
                print("ups", x)
                raise e
            except GeneratorExit as e:
                print("exit", x) 
                raise e
            else:
                print("else", x)
            finally:
                print("finally", x)
                
bar = Bar()
async for x in bar:
    if x == 2:
        break  # missing trio checkpoint?

print("--- Hello ---")
```

outputs:

```
else 0
finally 0
else 1
finally 1
--- Hello ---
exit 2
finally 2
```

When I put a `trio.sleep(...)` before the last print my use-case woks as expected. But This is not the solution I want. What can I do with my class `Bar` to fix this error?

```py
bar = Bar()
async for x in bar:
    if x == 2:
        break  # missing trio checkpoint?

await trio.sleep(0.001)
print("--- Hello ---")
```

outputs:

```
else 0
finally 0
else 1
finally 1
exit 2
finally 2
--- Hello ---
```

Comment: By the way, use of `await trio.sleep(0)` can totally be justified; Check document of `trio.sleep(seconds)` and it says following: *"seconds - May be zero to insert a checkpoint without actually blocking."* - which `asyncio.sleep(0)` also have similarity with AFAIK

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not trio specific.

You're getting this funny result because the generator is cleaned up sometime later. "async for" is syntactic sugar for creating an iterator with `__aiter__`, then calling `__anext__` on the result until that raises `AsyncStopIteration`. If that doesn't happen, `GeneratorExit` is thrown into the async iterator.

But how does the interpreter know that you're not going to call `__anext__` any more? Answer: the iterator goes out of scope and is then garbage collected. Garbage collection doesn't happen immediately but "some time later". In your case, either when your program exits or during `trio.sleep`.

How to fix this:

```
from async_generator import aclosing ## before py3.10
bar = Bar().__aiter__()  # aiter(bar) in py3.10
async with aclosing(bar):
    async for x in bar:
        if x == 2:
            break
```